# Ford-Fulkerson algorithm in a graph with links with weight 1

Tags: algorithm, graph

In a max flow problem, when I apply a ford-fulkerson algorithm to find the max flow, if all the links of the graph have weight 1, the max flow will be the number of paths that I've found in the ford fulkerson algorithm right? I mean, the number of dfs paths.

Thanks.

Comment: Where do all the max flow questions come from? Is it part of an ongoing contest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the maximum flow capacity is equal to the number of edge-distinct paths from source to sink.

Also, for the case of unit distances, most network flow algorithms have much stronger time complexity bounds then in general.

Comment: and then, according with the minimum cut theorem this the minimum cut will equals this maximum flow right?